# Removing values from one array and moving to another Array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat, array-splice

I have an array `$scope.multiRoles` , I need to remove the values inside it by clicking remove button. And the removed value should moved to another array `$scope.role`. I am able to remove the array by calling `removeRole()` but couldn't move the removed values into another array. Need assistance.

Html:

```
<div ng-if="rolesAdded" class = "col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <span class="tag label tagStyle newStyling" value ="data" ng-repeat="data in multiRoles track by $index">
    <span>{{data}}</span>
    <a><i ng-click="removeRoles(index)"class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign "></i></a> 
  </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.removeRoles = function(index){
  if(($scope.multiRoles!== null ) && ($scope.multiRoles.length>1)) {
    $scope.multiRoles.splice(index,1);                         
  }

  $scope.rolesAdded = true;
};
```

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911601/removing-a-value-from-an-array-and-moving-them-to-another-array)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pushing the value before splicing the array can work.

Try this:

```
 $scope.removeRoles = function(index){
            if(($scope.multiRoles!== null ) && ($scope.multiRoles.length>1)) {
          $scope.role.push($scope.multiRoles[index])
          $scope.multiRoles.splice(index,1);            

            }

            $scope.rolesAdded = true;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding it anywhere. And since you are using the index for your logic you need to add it in the other array before removing it. Consider this

```
$scope.removeRoles = function(index){
    if($scope.multiRoles !== null && $scope.multiRoles.length > 1) {
        $scope.role.push($scope.multiRoles[index]);
        $scope.multiRoles.splice(index,1);            
    }
    $scope.rolesAdded = true;
};
```

Also `$scope.role` should be an existing `array`

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.role = [];
$scope.removeRoles = function (index) {
if (($scope.multiRoles !== null) && ($scope.multiRoles.length > 1)) {
    $scope.role.push($scope.multiRoles[index])
    $scope.multiRoles.splice(index, 1);
}
$scope.rolesAdded = true;
};
```

Comment: You will have just push that element to the another array before remove it, that's it :)

Comment: Good job, but it's always nice if you could include more explanation of your code.

Comment: Yes yes that's right, but i wrote it from existing question's code. But your suggestion is actually good idea, Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution :

JS :

```
  $scope.removeRoles = function(index,data){

        if(($scope.multiRoles!== null ) && ($scope.multiRoles.length>1)) {
               var index = $scope.multiRoles.indexOf(data);
      $scope.multiRoles.splice(index,1);
             $scope.role.push(data);
```